# lua - "Attempt to Index a nil value" when a variable but not when it is a direct number"

Tags: variables, lua, null

I suspect this is a problem with a really simple solution. Essentially, if I use a variable to index an array, I get a nil error, but if I use a direct number, there is no issue. What about the variable *could* make it unusuable?

```
                        npcs[a].plotFind = 7
                        file:write("\n ".. npcs[a].plotarray[7].y) -- Doesn't produce a nil error
                        file:write("\n ".. npcs[a].plotarray[plotFind].y) -- Does produce a nil error
```

plotFind equals 7, and yet, the third line of code here produces a nil error, while the second line doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness, plotFind isn't the variable. npcs[a].plotFind is. I am dumb. Nevermind. Forgive my stupid.